# HTS7200 home theater replaced drive (hacked/tweaked) detects disc but won't play blu-ray only

Tags: repair, replacement, troubleshooting, home-theater

Downvote.... It doesn't fit on electronics.stackexchange.com, it doesn't fit here.... where else? Don't start to downvote, tell me where to go if it is wrong to place it here on this site.

---

Edit: Another downvote, this was the first question and the last.

---

I have a Philips HTS7200 home theater and replaced the old faulty drive with a blu-ray laptop drive because it is not replacable with an original one (not available and also drive quality is not the best - many consumers have problems).

This replacement is possible because the connection is a standard SATA connection so I have used an adapter to fit the design. I have used the old drive cabinet to tweak it into the design (not easy). The drive is powered directly from the internal power supply.

---

### [image: Internals HTS7200]

[image]

---

It plays any disc (CD/MP3/DVD) however detects blu-ray discs but won't play it. What could be the problem? When I press play I see message 1080i (which is okay) on the display and after this nothing happen. No error, nothing.

What could be the problem? Any ideas where to start?

Comment: RE: Downvote. The issue is the people on this site aren't necessarily experts on Stack Exchange as a whole and don't know where this question belongs.  The correct action is to make a close vote, but some people will inevitably downvote wrong-site-questions.  There was a [Gizmos.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) but that didn't make it.  You could try [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).  They say no media players, but you could make an argument that this is basically a computer?  Might not fly there tho.  Electronics.SE has the same note.

Comment: Thought in the mean time... Bluray disks are just software programs with DRM protected video streams.  There maybe a hardware check in your device to prevent swapping drives to follow some region locking or video stream decoding requirements. Device manufacturers have to follow a bunch of rules when making licensed Bluray players.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the kind help and your comments, take a look at it tomorrow. It plays all other discs fine (CD/MP3), also DVD (is also region based) except blu-ray. I start thinking about the power supply because I only use the 5V line because this is a 5V device. The old drive used both. Perhaps the 5V line is not capable (by design) to produce the required current (power consumption). I don't know blu-ray (the blue laser) consumes more power however a blue LED does (comparing to other colors like red, green, etc). There are two lasers, a (infra-)red one and a blue one. Figure out tomorrow

Comment: If the original drive was not blu-ray capable, then the other hardware may not have the code to read blu-ray discs even though it detects the presence.

Comment: @SolarMike : Thanks for your concern however this unit/model is designed to play blu-ray discs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, gave up on this Philips thing for now, don't spend more time on it (and money). The 'new' `LG CT10N` installed drive seems have some firmware problems (and cannot find a newer one than 1.5). It seems it is a common problem because there are consumers with the same problem.

I have two of these and used one in an USB enclosure to test the blu-ray functionality on a PC, detects the disc and after this same problem won't read blu-ray discs however can read all other formats. The error is some decoding problem.

So yeah, this is a big sad puppy (which is a shame), very nice design and construction quality. I don't want to take a risk it won't work again by buying other drive. Maybe I find one for free but for now don't want to spend any penny on it.

Thanks for the help everyone!

---

**Update:**

The new drive (`LG CT10N`) is now able to play blu-ray on PC, so the drive is really capable to play blu-ray discs. I use [VLC with added third-party codec](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0BCdozu2ug) and works however needs to be updated over time.

I think updates is the issue with the HTS7200 (there are no updates) because there are other people with the orginal drive that cannnot play some blu-ray discs or no blu-ray at all. Something with 'keys' that needs to be updated over time, it is a complicated and insane protected format. And also the compatibility with the system like somebody else noticed in the comments however is weird because it can play all kind of other discs, updates must be the reason for a PC-like device like this. On PC same story, can play everything whithout requirements except blu-ray (however able to fix it).

In modern standards, a stand-alone hardware device without updates (not supported anymore) become obsolete over time. ***"Please throw it away and buy a new one".*** No spare parts available, no tweaking allowed to keep it running. I have seen this with all kind of 'smart' devices like TV's, Phones, etc.

To the manufacturers: "You don't care about planet earth, do you?". Really frustrates me manufactures forcing products (hardware due software) to be obsolete while it is still cabaple of.